# How debug my code in List with NavigationView

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, navigationview

On the Canvas my code start correctly, but simulator send message about bug

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    //1
    var persons: [Member] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
```

break point stopped here

```
            List(persons) { person in
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    MemberDetail(name: person.name, headline: person.headline, bio: person.bio)
                }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(person.imageName).cornerRadius(40.0)
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(person.name)
                            Text(person.headline)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Persons"))
        }
    }
}
```

expectation

[image]

reality
[image]

Code struct of MemberDetails

```
struct MemberDetail: View {
    var name: String
    var headline: String
    var bio: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(name)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 4))
                .shadow(radius: 10)
            Text(name)
                .font(.title)
            Text(headline)
                .font(.subheadline)
            Divider()
            Text(bio)
                .font(.headline)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(50)
        }
            .padding(20)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(name), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

break points get error. I run my project on iphone 7 and simulator, but this not give solution

Comment: It looks like it is an issue on Apple‘s side. But without seeing `MemberDetail`, and having a minimum reproducible example it is difficult to know for sure. I would suggest updating your question to include the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue. If it transpires that it is an Apple issue then you should open a feedback with them.

Comment: first of all, I would recommend you to use a real device if you have bugs like this. The simulator and the canvas are a good idea but there are a lot of differences between those two options and a real iphone. 
If you want to check where the code break, you could use some breakpoints. Add a breakpoint at the beginning of your code, when you receive your images and when you receive your text . My first feeling is your MemberDetail is not correctly implemented, but you can check this by using breakpoints and some logging of your information.

Comment: Do run with same data as preview (test data) or other data that may contains empty image name or person data ?

Comment: I use iphone 7 and simulator any device but this not give solution @Iskandir

Comment: @Andrew I add code of MemberDetails, think about he is right

Comment: Run code with the same data which also run canvas @PtitXav

Comment: It looks like you are using only SwiftUI items and nothing that drops down into UIKit. I would be confident in saying that it is an Apple issue. You should submit a feedback to Apple https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

Comment: Except your are using wrong property in for Image in MemberDetails, it seems to be working fine on simulator and device iOS 16 xCode 14. Are you sure about image size as you do not set the size in the views ? may be a 0 size image.

Comment: @Andrew may be you are right, write to support, I'll keep you informed

Comment: Thanks for deleting my comment?! ^^ 
Did you tried another device, except the iphone 7 & simulator "any device"?Which iOS version you are developing for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely rewrote the code according to the guides from apple and it all worked

```
struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(landmarks) { landmark in
                NavigationLink {
                    LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
                } label: {
                    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Landmarks")
        }
    }
```